# PHP: How to render PDF reports containing charts?

Tags: php, symfony1, charts, pdf-generation, flot

I want to create PDF reports containing some pie/bar charts. I have to create them with my PHP web app and cannot use commandline tools. For the frontend I use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/). However, I don't know how to get these charts in a PDF, because my project is constrained to PHP.

How do I generate images from my charts to render a PDF?

Update: The solution has to be open source since my project will be open source, too.

Best,

Stefan

Answer (score 7):

Of course you won't be able to use a javascript charting solution to generate graphics to be used directly in a PDF. What you could do however, is use a PHP charting solution to create the graphs. Provided you have GD support built-in (it usually is) you could use [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) or [libChart](http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/introduction/) to create GIF/PNG charts you can embed within your PDF.

And for PDF generation I would personally recommend using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

Comment: wouldn't you be able to redirect user to a web page, generate the graphs on that page using JS library, save those graphs to an image, ... transmit that image to the server somehow, save it on the server, and then redirect user to the PDF page?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use PDFLib ?

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php

http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/graphics/fill-pattern/

Comment: Yes, I can use it. But I forgot to mention that my project will be open source and hence cannot use commercial libraries. I updated my question. But thanks for the hint.